# Convert the regex (1 + 01)∗ (0 + 10)+ to a NFA

Tags: regex

Convert the regex (1 + 01)∗(0 + 10)+ to a NFA.
The + in (0 + 10) is union and the + outside(0 + 10)+ is the Kleene star but not empty.

This is what I have so far. Im not sure if my answer is complete or if Im missing something.

[image: My progress so far.]

Comment: Hint: how would your automaton accept the valid input “101”? As far as I can tell you combined the two partial automata correctly, but both partial automate individually contain mistakes (the same kind of mistake).

Comment: I dont think 101 is a valid input...the first half of the NFA accepts 101 but It also needs some form of input from (0 + 10)+ because the + at the end of (0 + 10)+ means there must be a string from this part coz the + is the Kleene star which is not empty...

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, my mistake, apologies. Try “01100”, this should be valid: the prefix “01” is matched by the first subexpression. The next “10” is matched by the second subexpression, and so is the suffix “0”. But your NFA doesn’t accept it (it gets stuck in state “h”, which is non-accepting).

Comment: Once again, are you sure 01100 should be accepted? Coz if it gets a string of the form 10 from the second part of the expression, shouldn't the string be of the form (10)*? Or is it allowed to take on the 0 after the 10?

Comment: The second part of the expression matches “10” OR “0”, repeatedly (unless your regular expression is specified in a non-standard way). That’s why “10 0” is accepted by the second sub-expression.

Comment: ohh...thats what I thought...thanks...ill try to correct that. Any other mistakes?

Comment: The same kind of mistake is in the first part of the NFA … you have an arrow from “b” to “a”. This means that your first sub-NFA would accept “111”, but that’s invalid. Instead, the arrow should go all the way back to to the starting state, and the edge should be labelled with epsilon. Same for the other part of the union.

Comment: Ohh...so everywhere that I've transitioned back to a previous state should be replaced with a single transition from the last state of that sub-branch to the start state with an epsilon transition.